# ASP.NET Debugging Multiple Projects - Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging

I have two seperate ASP.NET applications on the single solution. I change the startup order of projects from menu in order to debug them. Although the first ASP.NET application can start on debug mode, the second one gets an error like this:

"
Unable to start debugging on the web server. Unable to do an AutoAttach.

Make sure the server is operating correctly. Verify there are no syntax errors in web.config by doing a Debug.Start Without Debugging.You may also want to refer to the ASP.NET and ATLServer debugging topic in the online documentation"

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the answer out here:

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t65889-auto-attach-aspnet_wp-exe-in-visual-studio.html

Hope it helps

EDIT: Here's the text from the site as requested:

Since a default web application is OK and the problem only occurs in this
specific web application, please check the following settings of the
problem project.

1. Open the problem project in VS.NET IDE.
2. Select Project->"Project Name" Properties...
3. Select Configuration Properties->Debugging.
4. Please make sure the "Start Action" is set to "Start project" and the
   "ASP.NET debugging" is enabled.

Comment: Please summarize the linked text in your answer. If the link breaks, this answer will be removed.